# 'Page editing error. Could not find property on type System.Object' after upgrading to Glass mapper v.4.0.9.60

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

We have recently upgraded our application from Glass mapper v3 to v.4.0.9.60 and facing this error 'Page editing error. Could not find property on type System.Object' on all properties in Edit mode. It works fine in live mode or preview mode.
Here are the details of our Glass mapper implementation:

Domain classes:

[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{XXXXX}", AutoMap = true)]

public interface CompanyInformationPage : BasePage
{

string CompanyName { get; set; }

}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{XXXXX}", AutoMap = true)]

public interface BasePage : ISitecoreItem

{

string Title { get; set; }

string Description { get; set; }

string Summary { get; set; }

Image Image { get; set; }

}

View:

```html
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<CompanyInformationPage>

<div class="company_page">
    <h1>@Editable(Model, x=>x.Title)</h1>
    @Html.Raw(@Editable(Model, x => x.Description))
</div>
```

We have tried removing GlassView as mentioned under http://glass.lu/Blog/GlassV4 (MVC Improvements) section but it didn't fix this issue.
We have also tried enabling z.Glass.Mapper.Sc.ViewRender.config.exclude file as per #198 but this also didn't work. We just renamed this file and removed '.exclude' extension and didn't make any changes in GlassMapperScCustom.cs file. Are we missing anything here?

Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a dummy "space" in your razor view? this is to force recompiling of the view again

Comment: Hi Ahmed, we tried this change and still getting the same error. We have also tried recycling of app pool.

Comment: Then you can open an issue on github https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper and explain the issue you are having

Comment: I've already logged this issue on github as well and waiting for response. Anyways, thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Hi Durgesh, have you found a fix or workaround for it? We are experiencing the same issue in our current project..

Comment: Hi Durgesh, have you found a fix or workaround for it? We are experiencing the same issue in our current project..

Comment: @MárcioDuarte: Hi Marcio, the only workaround I found is to convert the existing interfaces as models to classes. This supports Page editing and doesn't throw this exception.

Comment: Durgesh, that solved our problem. Thanks